How can I get Grafana Dashboard variables in Panel Javascript？
How can I get Grafana Dashboard variables, such as the $__from variable, in the Echarts panel? When I use the following JavaScript code to get this variable, I can’t retrieve it. However, it can be displayed in the panel title.

the variable working in panel title



the variable NOT working in Javascript



Try running this in console browser to test it out first.

grafanaRuntime.getDashboardSaveModel().getVariables()

The above will give you all the values for variables and then you pick up the value you want.

grafanaRuntime.getDashboardSaveModel().getVariables()[0].current.value

Grafana v10.4.0 - My version
